# Automatically determine tags while writing a question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, suggested-tags

Can we modify "Ask question" to automatically suggests tags based on your question content.

So instead that user needs to type "team-foundation-server" or "TFS" or "TeamFoundationServer" he will see list of tags auto-populated with ajax which he (or she) can then select and it will be associated with the question. So basically only thing we need is code which will cross-match question content with list of known tags while user is typing and display results in some nice ajax-enabled list/cloud/whatever UI control. This should be separate control for tags suggestions so user still has option to use standard tag list input to type-in tags.

In this case, instead of three (or more) tag variations we would have only one tag for Team-Foundation-Server.

Comment: Duplicate, [Automatic tag suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/auto-tagging)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was completed a while back. You'll see the suggested tag appear as soon as the tag predictor can pull enough from what you've written. A rather silly example (predicted tag circled in red):

[image]

Just give it a few seconds to determine the most appropriate tag(s), and you can click on them to apply them to your question.

Marking status-completed, a bit late, but better late than never :)

#### See also: [How are "Suggested Tags" chosen?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206907/how-are-suggested-tags-chosen)

Comment: Thanks Tim, I want to also update http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange but don't know when this was added. Can you please check and let us know? Earliest mention of this was back in [June 8, 2013](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183620/dont-suggest-tags-that-a-question-has-already-been-tagged-with) so it was probably somewhere nearby.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's as decent an approximation as any, so I'd say that's just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I actually like this idea.

Since it already finds questions that match the title, if you expanded the search out to also include the question body, you could then pull the most popular tags from that list of matching questions, that would already be a good starting point.

Otherwise you could possibly set up the keyword/synonym idea on tags and if it finds certain keywords in the text of the question or title it could bring up those tags as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Nice feature**. There are some drawbacks, though.

One needs to use the products, language name, tags he is talking about within the text. The usage has to be either exactly like the tag, or needs some stemming and synonyms. So using TFS should invoke the synonymous team-foundation-server tag. I see quite some work needed to be done.

Several attempts to introduce keyword/synonym, hierarchical, or onthological tag systems have been declined. But if nothing like this is used, the suggestions might be too weak or broad and not solve the problem.

When to populate the tag list with suggestions? When it is done whenever a blank or other whitespace is hit in the text, then the word in the text could also be "normalized" using the synonym, but the ajax traffic would be quite high.

One could do it whenever the taglist textbox is entered. But then, how would this work together with the preview that is in place now, suggesting based on typing in the taglist?

This feature seems to be quite complicated, but **very useful when done right**.

The only **real** drawback I see though is that if poorly done, many will be accepting the suggestions anyway and we will end up with poor tagging. So don't prepopulate the taglist, but suggest in some other way.

Comment: Hierarchical designs have indeed been declined. Synonyms are already used in some fashion in the system and could probably be expanded more to allow for it. And as far as the accuracy, that is just a simple case of only getting out of it what you put into it. There's nothing you can do about that, and you aren't forcing the users to select from the preselected tags anyway, they are just there for suggestion.

Comment: I agree with prepopulating the tag list. This should be only suggestion cloud and it should be added next to the tag list. User should still be able to decide that he wants to provide own tags instead selecting from the suggestion cloud. Two SEPARATE things :-)