# Can a suggested tags feature be added?

Tags: feature-request, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-tagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/auto-tagging)

Can tags be suggested after you enter your question? This would make it easy to pick tags that I might not have thought to add.

Comment: This has been brought up before. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/auto-tagging